# C++/CLI virtual method, can't use the virtual method in derived class

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

Okei, i'm quit new to C++/CLI so this should be an easy question.
I am trying to use a virtual method from an abstract class.

Here is my code:

```
// Figurer.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace Figurer {

public ref class Figur
{
public:
    virtual double areal();
    virtual double omkrets();
};

public ref class Sirkel : public Figur
{
private:
    double radius;
    double static PI = 3.141593;
public:
    Sirkel(double sirkelradius){
        radius = sirkelradius;
    }
    double areal(){
        return radius * radius * PI;
    }

};
}
```

Visual studio tells me: Error: 'new' or 'override' is required because this declaration matches function "Figurer::Figur::areal"

Comment: `public ref class`? This isn't C++.

Comment: haha, what? but it's visual c++?

Comment: Its Managed C++, so it is C++. Maybe you should add the ManagedC++ tag (if such exists)

Comment: @MatthiasB: If it's Managed C++, then it's not C++.

Comment: In standard C++, there is no problem with the `areal` function . It is recommended to tag it `override` but not required.

Comment: Try changing `double areal()` to `double areal() override`. I'm not familiar with managed C++, but the error message seems to ask for this.

Comment: today it would rather go by the name [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted the error message and the solution:

```
Error: 'new' or 'override' is required because this declaration matches function "Figurer::Figur::areal"
```

So you either need to use `new` or `override` in front of the function signature:

```
virtual double areal() override  {
    return radius * radius * PI;
}
```

---

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41w3sh1c.aspx

Comment: Boths gives an error.

(override)Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.

(new)Error: expected a declaration

Comment: I guess you need a `virtual` before the signature.